# html-pdf or 'pdf-creator-node' generaes me pdf but it is cut into partial with big fonts ,node js

Tags: node.js, pdf, html-pdf, node-html-pdf

with this code

```
let options = {
        format: 'A4',
        orientation: 'portrait',
        border: '2mm',
        header: {
            height: '15mm',
            contents: '<h4 style=" color: red;font-size:20;font-weight:800;text-align:center;">CUSTOMER INVOICE</h4>'
        },
        footer: {
            height: '20mm',
            contents: {
                first: 'Cover page',
                2: 'Second page',
                default: '<span style="color: #444;">{{page}}</span>/<span>{{pages}}</span>', 
                last: 'Last Page'
            }
        }
    }

      // let PDF = await pdfMaster.generatePdf("template.hbs", { data }, options);

      // const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'report.pdf');
      // fs.writeFileSync(filePath, PDF);

    // const templatePath = path.join(__dirname, 'template.hbs');

    // // Compile Handlebars template
    // const template = fs.readFileSync(templatePath, 'utf8');
    // const compiledTemplate = handlebars.compile(template);
    // const html = compiledTemplate({ data });
    // console.log(html)
    
    // // Options for PDF generation
 
    // // Output PDF path
    // const pdfPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'report.pdf');
    
    // // Generate PDF from the compiled HTML
    // pdf.create(html, options).toFile(pdfPath, (err) => {
    //     if (err) return console.error('Error generating PDF:', err);
    //     console.log('PDF generated successfully:', pdfPath);

    // });        

    const html = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'template.html'), 'utf-8');
    const document = {
      html: html,
      data: {
          products: data
      },
      path: './docs/' + 'report.pdf'
  }

  pdf.create(document, options)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

with this code i get pdf zoomed and my content is always out of the boundary i use bootstrap on my template html and the same template works fine with pdfmaster which as puppetere complication on my server side is there any way to solv the issue